# Android: Determine the previously displayed external Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

In my application, I used a library that displays ads in my app. When a user clicks on the ad, it launches the Browser app, and the `onClick` events are handled by the library itself.

I also have a placed code in `onPause()` and `onStart()` methods that detects whether any of my Activities are sent to background (user pressed Home) or switching between any of my Activities.

So if the app is either freshly opened (no instance is running) or re-opened from background, it will display a dialog box. If the user is only switching from any of my Activites, then the dialog box shouldn't be displayed.

Now the problem is that when the user clicks on an Ad, the Browser app gets loaded and would mean that my App has been sent to background, and so when the user closes the Browser, it will still display the dialog box when it shouldn't.

Is it even possible for my App to determine the previously displayed external Activity (ie. Browser) and not display the dialog box?

Or are there better approaches that I can follow in implementing such setup?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a way for your Activity to know, which was the previous activity. A simple work-around is to save the time the dialog was displayed and not displayed it again, before some time passes. You can decide on the exact time period based on your application's requirements.

This may be in fact better in some situations. If the user switches from the Browser to your application and it has been some time he has used your application, it will be appropriate to show the dialog again.

Comment: hi, it's a specific requirement not to show the dialog when the user switched back from the Browser to my application. So its unfortunate that there's no way to determine the previous activity.

Answer (score 0):

you can use onResume() method to specify the behaviour when your activity get back from the background.

Comment: onResume() is still called when I switch between my App's activities, so it would basically be the same logic as with what's in my onStart().